# Is there a better way of sending messages to specific channels in specific servers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a logs script, however, I can not get it to work. Is there a better way?

I've tried switching around the properties, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
client.on('message', message => {
  var sender = message.member.user.tag
  var channel = message.channel.name
  var message = message.content
  var server = message.guild
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .addField('**' + sender + '** said ' + message + ' in ' + channel + ', ' + server)
    .setColor('#4286f4')

  // This is the line I'm having problems with:
  client.guilds.get('575957043211403265').channels.get('575957043211403267').sendEmbed(embed);
});
```

Comment: You can skip retrieving the guild and just get the channel from the client. `client.channels.get(id)`. Although you don't really say what your problem with the line is.

Comment: But the messages that I want to be sent to the channel are in a different server, and just having `client.channels.get(id)` doesn't work either

Comment: From the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels)... `this will be every channel in every guild` ... Id should be the id on the channel you want (regardless of guild)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the IDs you're using are correct, then your code should be valid, **as long as you're using the library from the `stable` branch**.
You're using the [`TextChannel.sendEmbed()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=sendEmbed) method, which is deprecated: that means that it'll be removed in the future versions. If you installed the `master` branch that method won't be available (check the docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=sendEmbed)).

There is another way of sending embeds:

```
TextChannel.send({ embed: yourEmbed });
```

In your case, it would be:

```
client.guilds.get('575957043211403265').channels.get('575957043211403267').send({ embed });
```

If that doesn't work, please include the error in your reply, you might have missed something in the question :)